# Not null constraint violation for non-existing field

Tags: hsqldb, sqlexception, non-nullable

I create the following relational table with a primary key (Liquibase script below):

```
  <changeSet author="..." id="1661758077399">
    <createTable tableName="idp_groups">
      <column name="idp_id" type="VARCHAR(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="enterprise_group_id" type="UUID">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>

  <changeSet author="..." id="1661758077399-2">
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="idp_id, enterprise_group_id" constraintName="idp_groups_pkey" tableName="idp_groups"/>
  </changeSet>
```

There are no foreign keys created, just a primary key.
Then I try to add some test sql data like this:

```
 insert into idp_groups (idp_id, enterprise_group_id)
 values ('1234', '10d5584f-f2c6-4534-9224-1758de383cd7');

 insert into idp_groups (idp_id, enterprise_group_id) values ('1234',
 '20d5584f-f2c6-4534-9224-1758de383cd7');

 insert into idp_groups (idp_id, enterprise_group_id)
 values ('2345', '40d5584f-f2c6-4534-9224-1758de383cd7');
```

The test db is hsql (latest version):

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
>   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
>   <version>2.7.0</version>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

The test itself:

```
  @Sql({
      "/data/idps.sql",
      "/data/groups.sql",
      "/data/idp_groups.sql"
  })
  @Test
  public void testSyncTask() {
    when(rbacIdpGroupsClient.getIdpGroups(any(), eq("1234"), any(), any(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(
        getRbacResponseIdp1());
    when(rbacIdpGroupsClient.getIdpGroups(any(), eq("2345"), any(), any(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(
        getRbacResponseIdp2());

    idpGroupSynchronizer.syncGroupsRbac();
  }
```

And I get the following error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data/idp_groups.sql]: insert into idp_groups (idp_id, enterprise_group_id) values ('1234', '10d5584f-f2c6-4534-9224-1758de383cd7'); nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10265 table: IDP_GROUPS column: IDP_ENTITY_ID

SYS_CT tables are automatically created by [hsql](http://hsqldb.org/doc/changelog_1_7_1.txt) for constraints reasons.
However it doesn't make any sense as I'm providing both columns in the insert, so there is no null value..
Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem on HSQL's end?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was I had enabled ddl-auto, so Hibernate was creating additional tables and columns according to my entities.
After switching to ddl-auto none, the problem disappeared:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```